# Android Studio not starting: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndex

Tags: android, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio, and now when I am starting it is giving me this error. How can I resolve it?

```
 Internal error. Please report to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndex'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:159)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:46)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:524)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndex'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:244)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:39)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:570)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:590)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:225)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:212)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:199)
    at org.picocontainer.alternatives.AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.getComponentInstance(AbstractDelegatingMutablePicoContainer.java:75)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:121)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:371)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:89)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:508)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:151)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\UserName\.AndroidStudio\system\index\todoindex\TodoIndex.ver (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.initExtensions(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:332)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.initComponent(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:359)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:548)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\UserName\.AndroidStudio\system\index\todoindex\TodoIndex.ver (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.IndexInfrastructure$1.execute(IndexInfrastructure.java:95)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.IndexInfrastructure$1.execute(IndexInfrastructure.java:90)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.doIOOperation(FileUtilRt.java:517)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.IndexInfrastructure.rewriteVersion(IndexInfrastructure.java:90)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.registerIndexer(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:390)
    at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl.initExtensions(FileBasedIndexImpl.java:290)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: I have seen a few reports of people rebooting and seeing the error fixed. Here is one reference: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60056

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a similar issue posted on Androids open source bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74458

The solution was to restart your computer. Try this and see if it works.

Comment: Restarting worked for me on windows 7 Android Studio 3.2.1, Thanks.

Comment: For me, the reboot was sufficient. Both 3.4 beta 3 and 3.5 canary were throwing this error on startup, but a reboot resolved it. thanks

Comment: 2021 and still a valid answer!

Answer (score 24):

This works without the loss any settings or project. It will take you to your previous state at the time of editing an open file.

1. Go to your home directory. ie `/home/XXXXXX/.AndroidStudio.X.X`
2. Rename the `.AndroidStudio.X.X` to any thing else i.e. `back_up/`
3. Run your android studio
4. It will prompt you to import current setting or create a new version
5. Choose the import setting and select the `back_up/` directory

Bravo you are good to go.

Comment: Worked with PyCharm too, seems to work with all Jetbrains IDEs. Thanks :)

Comment: Worked on IntelliJ but can't use the old import settings. "I do not want to import existing setting"(3rd option) helped.

Comment: Android Studio 2.3 blows up every time, regardless of whether I import settings from 2.3, from 1.5, from 1.3, or if I chose not to import any settings.

Comment: on mac u will find it in /Users/{username}/Library/Application\ Support/Google/{AndroidStudioxxx}

Answer (score 18):

The Easiest solution that works for the latest Android Studio:

1. Check the **latest Plugin [check by date and time]** installed in Android Studio `C:\Users\{Username}\.AndroidStudio\config\plugins` directory. ***{Mostly Third-party Plugin is the cause}***
2. **Go Forward Delete that plugin [`.jar file`].** - no need to delete/rename the whole directory as suggested by others.
3. **Close Android Studio properly** - through Task Manager or through Restarting your Computer.

Problem solved !!! Cheers.

Comment: I deleted the plugin which gave error, from path /Users/user_name/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.3/

Comment: I had to remove the plugin "Android NDK Support" to make Android Studio work again. After doing this, I was able to build my APK/Bundle (which has native code) from Android Studio and it seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Solved this problem.

For me, all above methods are useless.

Then I guess maybe the plugin installed newly cause the error .

I empty the plugins at the directory of `C:\Users\...\.AndroidStudio\config\plugins`
and it work normally.

Comment: Windows 10 Android Studio 3.1.2
Work for me, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

do the following steps :
**1.** **Delete your Old System Environment Variables**(e.g JAVA_HOME,GRADLE_HOME,ANDROID_HOME or ...)
**2.** **Restart your pc**
**3.** **Set Environment Variables Again**
**4.** **Lunch Android Studio**

Answer (score 1):

It's the IRIS plugging which is disabled.(for MACOS)
If you go on the android studio starter window, you go on configure Menu ~> plugins ~>installed ~> Iris

And you switch disable to enable

Worked for me , on the contrary of restarting computer or removing Lib/Caches/...

Comment: Thank you very much. I clicked on plugins --> installed and removed the checkmark form IRIS ... now I can open my projects!

Answer (score 1):

### Do the followings

1. Restart your computer
2. Delete the .AndroidStudio.X.X folder from %USERPROFILE%.
3. Set the Environment Variable
    ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\
    ANDROID_SDK_HOME = C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\
4. Restart Your Computer >> Start Android Studio >> Choose "Do Not Import Settings"
   And Here you Go....Enjoy, Happy Learning!

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem. and then i research the problem. i founded a solution which working for me. 
i changed the system language in macO

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the error comes from Cache folder so I removed all the Android Studio related folders in this path: `~/Library/Caches/` and also as Eng Chrisp mentioned all the old settings from `~/.AndroidStudioXXX`. Make sure you export all your settings before deleting these directories. You can do so by using Export Settings option in File menu of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this after the upgrade to 2.2 (on Windows 7 Pro). I tried all of the solutions above, and combinations, including going back to an earlier config (.AndroidStudio2.1 and .AndroidStudio2.0 in my Users directory) and specifying no earlier config to import. Nothing fixed it. So here's what did: I reinstalled Android Studio from a fresh download. I let it de-install the previous install, but did NOT let it reinstall the SDK, pointing it to the existing SDK install instead (I did NOT want to redownload the various system images I use on my slowish internet). That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me under Windows 7 Environment, this solution worked:

> In order to fix this
>   issue, please ensure your JAVA_HOME is pointing to **C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102** (Java SE Development Kit) instead of
>   **C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102** (Java SE Runtime Environment). In
>   fact, JRE is located inside JDK folder.
>
> If you haven't installed JDK yet, please do it following next link:
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnes

**Quote my source:** https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211766#c8

Answer (score 0):

For me,

I just uninstalled the Android Studio and again reinstalled.

And then some dependencies had to add.

Then it work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

As of 15/01/2018 Intellij doesn't start with Java9 and throws this error. Set JAVA_HOME to java8.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to ~\system\caches make backup of caches  delete all the files in caches folder

Restart Android Studio and it will work like butter.

Tried it on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

As I can't comment [MrOnyancha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32141497/7740405), I write an "new" answer (not enough reputation) :

I solved my problem by simply remove C:\Users\{my_name}\.AndroidStudioX.X as his solution didn't work for me.
At the next start of Android Studio, I had the installation wizard but any SDK had to be downloaded, might be done offline...

Comment: Separate solutions, while they're similar to others, aren't comments when they're different enough. You delete a different folder, which makes this a separate solution. Hence, it's an answer and not a comment

Comment: I might have written a little mistake (I don't remember if there's a point between Studio and "X" on my folder's name) but it's the same folder.

Comment: if you've made a mistake or need to add more information, you can always [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51610328/edit) your post.

Comment: I confirm there's no point, but when I commented I was not on my work computer and didn't have the folder (I wouldn't say "I don't remember" if I could check). I know I can edit my post, I edited this one

Answer (score 0):

This might be the problem caused by a newly added plugin . so remove it by following Fordo Alexandera's answer.It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For me, without reinstalling anything: 
The problem was caused by a new plugin. In users/.../config/plugins I removed the plugin file and its entry from `extensions.xml`. Then my IDE started working again.

Answer (score 0):

install jdk 8 different version will give error

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall plugin directly from Android Studio launcher.
Configuration -> plugins -> uninstall the error component.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the low memory error on Android studio, just enlarge it and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

just delete the folder "marketplace"

located :
C:\Users\usename.AndroidStudio4.0\config\plugins

regards