# Android Studio 2.3 Cannot Load Project StartupAbortedException

Tags: android, android-studio

This morning I updated my version of Android Studio from 2.2 to 2.3 and I got this message when I try to load any project. Any idea?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: try this answer might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/32141497/7604342

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BlackBerry plugin is crashing. Disable it in `Preferences -> Plugins` and then be a good citizen by sending the error logs to the BB team.