# Android Studio IDE is not starting

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, ide

I am trying to start Android studio but before start, it shows some exception. I don't know how to solve this issue. Please help. I am using android studio 3.1.1.

This is the log message:

> I have deleted Android studio and reinstall after that it is working fine. All the mentioned solution did not work for me.
>   Thanks

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:213)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:49)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:346)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:276)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:515)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:119)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$9(ApplicationImpl.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:543)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:488)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:454)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:103)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:406)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:392)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:206)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: Duplicate: [Fatal error initializing intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003717/android-studio-not-starting-fatal-error-initializing-com-intellij-util-indexin/32141497)

Comment: But Restart is not working

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning, I also faced these issues so  There are some a similar issue posted on Androids open source bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74458

The solution was to restart your computer. Try this and see if it works.

and also check JDK environment :

Open Start menu > computer > System Properties > Advanced System Properties In the Advanced tab > Environment Variables, add new system variable JAVA_HOME that points to your JDK folder, for example C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21.

Comment: Figured it out! I'm sure someone will run into this in the future, so here goes. 

Even though it found my JDK during installation, it wasn't able to find it when I was trying to open it, for some reason. Simple fix. Add a `JDK_HOME` environment variable to your system variables. It should contain the path to your JDK's **ROOT** directory. i.e. `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\`